# How to access a value which is defined inside a div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can we access a value which is defined inside the element? I tried this code, but it's not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log($("div#named").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="named" Items='10'>Hello World!!</div>
```

Comment: 1) `Items` should be a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) which you can pick up with [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/). 2) Is that the value you're trying to get, or do you want the text content of the div?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers **what the expected behavior should be**. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Answer (score 2):

Assuming by 'value' you mean the 'Items' attribute, then use `attr()`:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  console.log($("div#named").attr('Items'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="named" Items="10">Hello World!!</div>
```

***However*** you should note that `Items` is not a standard HTML attribute and will cause your HTML to be invalid.

The correct way to add any metadata to an element is to use a `data` attribute instead. You can then read this using jQuery's `data()` method:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  console.log($("div#named").data('items'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="named" data-items="10">Hello World!!</div>
```